# Creating context menus in d3 - canvas element is empty

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, contextmenu

I've been following this example to create a right click context menu in a d3 graph:
http://jsfiddle.net/thudfactor/dzw9h/

The 'contextmenu' event is overriden correctly and it enters the relevant code when doing a right click. However this line returns as [[null]]

```
canvas = d3.select(".canvas");
```

and hence the rest of the code is also returning null or failing.

Can someone perhaps shed a light where the .canvas property should coming from? It didn't look like it was set somewhere in the example code.
Thank you.
If it matters, I'm working with d3 version 3.5.0

Comment: Have you got a canvas element with the class name `canvas`?

Comment: you have got a div with class canvas `<div class="canvas">` .... and `canvas = d3.select(".canvas");`  line does not return null